why doesn't open drain output go all the way down to GND?
To start off, this is working fine but in doing some testing I am not sure WHY the open drain output is not going all the way down to GND.
I am using a MAX16055 power monitor to drive the power on reset into a Zynq 7000 SOC, a reset LED (driven from a 74AC14 inverter), and some other external reset circuits.
The reset output of this device is open drain and I am using a 10K pull-up to 3.3V. I do have a watchdog circuit on this line as well with a 'crude' method to disable through a jumper. Basic schematic is shown below.
When I force a push-button reset, the output goes to ~0.25V.
Also, with the WDIS jumper installed a reset drives this to ~0.6V.
Why doesn't this go all the way to 0V?
The datasheet (www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX16055.pdf) shows VOL is MAX between 0.3-0.4V at 1-2mA.  Is this just a result of the RDSON of the internal device?  What is the typical limit for a typical open drain output (is it the absolute max rating of 20mA)?


When you have the WDIS jumper installed your pull-up value is only 100 ohms. That's a lot for a device that is rated for Vol at 2mA, which explains why you're not getting a good 'low' out of it (Yes, it's due to its internal Rds(on).)
A little bit of active circuitry can fix this (simulate it here):

The NPN transistor is wired as a pass element. When the WDT Disable switch is open, the transistor will be on when its emitter is pulled low by the WDT, which will also pull RESETn low. When WDT disable is closed, the NPN will be off, so WDT will have no effect.

Thanks for the response. I wasnt really concerned with the wdis jumper. I just wanted to include it since it was there. It is not normally  connected. So without that circuit, i was more concerned with the 0.25v case. Just seemed high for the small load i have (3.3/10k + 74ac14). Also, the datasheet is showing the vol voltage at a specific voltage and load current. I would have preferred a graph or a different parameter... I.e. didnt think that 2ma was the rating to use.

The AC14 should present no load since it’s cmos. You didn’t show the 3.3k, but that could be made higher.

No 3.3k. was saying 3.3v/10k is only 0.33mA. nowhere near the 2mA on the datasheet. So with that small load, i didnt understand why i see .25v and not something closer to zero.

I don’t understand either. There must be some unaccounted for loading in the circuit that is eluding notice. Maybe the watchdog timer chip is the push-pull variety instead of open drain?
